# PHP: How to capture a timeout on a dio_read()?

Tags: php, serial-port

I am using `dio_read` in PHP to capture input from a serial device (specifically the USB IR Toy v2 from Dangerous Prototypes).

Sometimes the input from the device is slow (10+ seconds). I'd like to timeout the `dio_read`, but not sure how.

If someone reading this post knows how, could you help point me in the right direction? thanks.

Comment: No idea if it works with filehandles on serial devices, but try http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php

Comment: Yes. :-) There is at least one person here who knows how. If I post that as an answer, will you accept it as correct? If not, can I change it to no, no one here will know? Will you accept that instead? This is not a specific question; please edit to make it one. Thanks. :-)

Comment: You can answer your own questions. I'm not going to post it, since I was just taking a wild stab in the dark.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: @KenWhite not sure if that's sarcasm or what...

Comment: @MarcB Unfortunately, PHP complains that the supplied resource is not a valid stream resource. Oh well.

Comment: The PECL version of DIO http://pecl.php.net/package/dio looks like it supports what you want, but I failed to find any documentation on how to use it :-(

Answer (score 1):

dio_read on Windows (other platforms unknown) will not timeout if there is no data to read. There is no way to specify a timeout or do a non-blocking read on Windows.
http://php.net/dio_read

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dio_fctnl()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dio-fcntl.php) to set the file descriptors flags to **O_NONBLOCK** or **O_ASYNC**